# What is WindowsTokenRoleProvider for?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

What is WindowsTokenRoleProvider for?

Can I delete it from web.config?

I'm using forms authentication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.windowstokenroleprovider.aspx) explains it:

> Gets role information for an ASP.NET application from Windows group membership.

This means that the user roles will be obtained from Windows groups. So you can remove it if you don't want to use Windows group roles.